# Spring, hibernate type mapping based on different database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate-mapping

I have something like this for defining the hibernate type mapping in the entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TEST_TABLE")
public class Test {

     @Type( type = "jsonb" )
     @Column(name = "CONTENT_FILES")
     private List<ContentFile> contentFiles;

}
```

which map an entity field to a custom defined hibernate type jsonb for supporting PostgreSQL DB.

I would like to change the mapping to another hibernate custom type json for supporting MSSQL DB.

Can I support both mappings in the same entity class?

I tried to use the @Profile annotation but it doesn't work.

```
@Profile("pgsql")
@Type( type = "jsonb" )
@Profile("mssql")
@Type( type = "json" )
@Column(name = "CONTENT_FILES")
private List<ContentFile> contentFiles;
```

Comment: Are you planning to connect your application to two different databases at the same time ?@Peter Chau

Comment: That is why the JPA spec allows an `orm.xml` in which you can override these things for a specific database.

Comment: @LahiruWijesekara I would like to connect only one of the database, based on the profile settings.

Comment: You can try out below solution and share your results@PeterChau

Answer (score 1):

json and jsonb both data types are almost identical according to the PostgreSQL documentation.Therefor you don't have to maintain two different data types to keep json in MSSQL and in PostgreSQL . 
Please refer to below link of 
[PostgreSQL documentation.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/datatype-json.html)